# A homegrown simple riddle

Tags: riddle

> Every day back and forth I go
>
> I lean forward and back and my legs move four.
>
> No matter how hard I try
>
> No matter the time I move my legs
>
> I will never move from my place by my own power.

Hint #1

> I look like I live but yet I do not.

**What am I?**

Comment: Sorry if the riddle is unclear. First riddle I wrote

Comment: Don't worry, looks good - the only thing I'm pondering is whether you mean physical or metaphorical legs (but thats just part of the riddle - don't change that!) Welcome to puzzling

Comment: They've been here BG :P - Is it by chance someone who's paralyzed stuck in a rocking chair unable to move themselves?

Comment: @n_palum I put a subtle hint

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are a

> Rocking Horse

It is basically the same answer as [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/53393/36638) but it follows your hint that it looks alive.

Comment: Well done. The other one was just wrong enough not to be right

Comment: ...answered too late

Comment: Admittedly, @Christopher, I didn't care much for this riddle. It was a bit too broad and vague. I think it could benefit from some misdirection and affirmation. A subtle "pummel" or "look in the mouth" or even "of course" would have gone a long way to show it should have been a horse and not a chair.

Comment: Also, @Christopher, there is no need for one to indeed to be used everyday. My daughter has one she only uses when friends come over. I think it could have used a little workshopping. A decent effort, but would prefer something more clearly "horsey" from the lines.

Comment: Well it was my first attempt to write a riddle but I didn't know you guys had a sandbox/workshop

Comment: No worries, I mean the criticism very friendly. I don;t know if we have a formal workshop, but I think you could get some good feedback in The Sphinx Lair if you requested.

Comment: There is actually a [riddle sandbox](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5276/the-riddle-sandbox) and at one time every new riddle here had to go through it. It's pretty much completely unused now.

Comment: @Christopher, I understand your annoyance but your response to n_palum is really unnecessarily rude; please [be nice](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) here.

Comment: @n_palum I understand your annoyance too, but it wouldn't hurt to be a little nicer to newcomers.

Comment: (I have deleted both the comments in question now.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan what? I never tried to be rude. Sorry if that happened

Comment: I don't even remember the comments in question. Could you mod message me them?

Comment: Mod messages are generally meant to be used only when a user has done something bad, and I worry that if I send you one it may make some automatic system in the bowels of the Stack Exchange machinery think worse of you. So I'll say here that you said something like "Cry me a river, build a bridge, and get over it". I'll remove this message again once I know you've read it.

Answer (score 7):

Are you a

> rocking chair?

Every day back and forth I go

I lean forward and back and my legs move.

> rocking chairs have legs and rock back and forth.

No matter how hard I try

No matter the time I move my legs

I will never move from my place by my own power.

> rocking chairs need someone to rock them.

### **Guess 2**

You are a

> rocking horse

Every day back and forth I go

I lean forward and back and my legs move.

> rocking horses have legs and rock back and forth.

No matter how hard I try

No matter the time I move my legs

I will never move from my place by my own power.

> rocking horses need someone to rock them.

Hint #1

> look like I live but yet I do not.
> It looks like a horse.

Comment: This seems more likely - +1

Comment: That does seem likely, though is it really true that rocking chairs move their legs no matter the time?  What if there's nobody in them?

Comment: If my joke is right I'll be disappointed

Comment: Also @Grumpyllama59 consider using spoiler formatting :)

Comment: @puzzledPig It's not saying "no matter what time my legs move" it is saying, "no matter when I move my legs, I will never move myself"

Comment: @n_palum Ohhh, now I feel foolish. Thank you for that clarification!

Comment: @puzzledPig you should know by now its ghosts that rock rocking chair ;)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil yikes, I forgot about the ghosts *again*? I must be really out of it today...

Comment: Super close but no cigar

Comment: I updated the riddle with a small hint

Comment: @Christopher if the answer is just 'chair' or a version of a chair, I think you should consider this answer correct and just comment what the intended type was

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil it is not a chair

Comment: Added a hint to the riddle

Answer (score 5):

I think you are a

> plant

Title:

> You can grow plants at home

Every day back and forth I go

> Being blown in the wind?

I lean forward and back and my legs move.

> Plant sways and the roots are always growing

No matter how hard I try
No matter the time I move my legs
I will never move from my place by my own power.

> The plant can't move on its own however hard it moves its roots (the legs)

What am I?

> A plant?

Comment: Clever but not the answer. I may have a few errors in my riddle

Comment: I had an error in my riddle but I fixed it, a bit unclear

Comment: @n_palum update makes my answer valid but incorrect still :P

Comment: Added a hint to the riddle

Answer (score 4):

Are you just a:

> Chair - since you clarified 4 legs.

Every day back and forth I go

I lean forward and back and my legs move.

> Chairs have 4 legs and are moved back and forth each day while people move them in and out of tables to eat.

No matter how hard I try

No matter the time I move my legs

I will never move from my place by my own power.

> Chairs need someone to move them.

However, I think there's many things that possibly fit at this time.

> Tables, Couch, Chair, Wheelchair + Person, Desk, Baby who can't move yet on all fours.

Comment: If it is this I think 'rocking chair' should be considered correct.

Comment: Well technically since they've added the 4 leg rule, it's not. As most have the 2 curved legs, hence the rocking.

Comment: [I'd argue it does haves legs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aASo5.jpg) - and the 2 curved pieces of woods are just attachments, or 'feet'. There are still 4 visible wooden bits coming off the chair

Comment: It is not the answer I am looking for

Comment: Those are actually called rockers and the legs connect the rest of the chair to the rockers(if we're being this technical)... just sayin' ;)

Comment: Added a hint to the riddle

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance a

> clock (specifically one with a pendulum)?

Every day back and forth I go

> The pendulum (of a grandfather clock for example) swings back and forth, every day

I lean forward and back and my legs move.

> (if you can consider the hands of a clock as its legs, then this works... or is that too much of a stretch?)

No matter how hard I try

No matter the time I move my legs

> The hands of a clock never stop moving, no matter the time

I will never move from my place by my own power.

> Though it does move, the clock will always remain in one place in a house/building.

Comment: They're considered hands of a clock, saying they're legs to fit the puzzle is too much of a stretch.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was afraid of...